# chrome.cookies.get() Invalid value for argument 0. Property 'name'

Tags: jquery, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a jquery extension where I'm doing something like:

```
var c = chrome.cookies.get({url:"some-web-site"});
```

in my popup.html file.

When I tryt to run the extension it gives the following error:

Uncaught Error: Invalid value for argument 0. Property 'name': Property is required.

and gives jqury.min.js:16 as the location (I am including jquery from a google CDN).

As soon as I comment out the above code, the extension runs fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify both url and name of the cookie.

```
var c = chrome.cookies.get({url:"some-web-site", name: "cookie-name"});
```

Comment: wow... i feel stupid, i was looking at the getAll method and saw the optional string description for name. thank you.